# How to convert multiple tables with same columns into one table in postgress

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I have a Postgres database that carry over 200 tables with the same column names and datatypes respectively. I would like to join all of them into one table, how can I achieve this?

I have Postgres 9.4 and pgAdmin setup.

Comment: Maybe `CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2 UNION ALL ...`?

Comment: @DanielLyons this will be the longest sql statement I write in 2015! Is there a way to load all tables at once? or with pgql and some shell script!

Comment: Stupid problems beget stupid solutions. :) There is no built-in way to do it. Obviously, you can script it; if you use bash, you may find `psql -c -At` to be a useful set of flags, and you can query the information schema to get the list of tables.

Comment: Also, you could create the table first and then issue 200 `INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM tableN` statements.

Comment: actually you just inspired me! I can write a shell script to generate all the table names ( I have a sql dump of all of them ) then run the query as you suggested! but I wonder if there is a better way though!

Comment: No, there is no better way. Next time achieve 3NF and you won't have to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If the tables have identical column names and types, then you can create a parent table and arrange for all of the other tables to inherit from the parent table. After this, queries on the parent table will automatically query all of the child tables.

First create an empty parent table with the same definition as the 200 tables you already have.

Then, use `ALTER TABLE` on each of the 200 tables to make them inherit from the parent table.

```
CREATE TABLE myparenttable( LIKE mychildtable1 );

-- Repeat this for each of the child tables
ALTER TABLE mychildtable1 INHERIT myparenttable;
```

See also: [Inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html) in the postgresql manual.

Comment: is there a way to specify the schema from psql? like this  psql -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres  --schema mySchema  -f data.sql

Comment: well, I added the schema inside the sql like so  mySchema.tablename